# What does $f^n(x)$ mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What does $f^n(x)$ mean? When known :

> $f(x) = ax + b$
>
> $f^1(x)=f(x)$
>
> $f^n(x) =f(f^{n-1}(x))$ for $n=2,3,4..$

Express $f^n (x) (n=2,3,4..)$ in terms of $a,x,b,n$

I dont know what should i attempt, i dont even know what the question means.

Comment: Hint: $f^2(x)=a(ax+b)+b$.

Comment: Here it means compose $f$ with itself $n$ times

Comment: Sometimes my brain not work properly. But thanks people here

Answer (score 1):

It just means you evaluate $f$ that many times, each time using as input the previous output, and starting with $x$. $f^4(x)$ is $f(f(f(f(x)))$.

Answer (score 1):

$f^n(x)$ can mean different things in different contexts.

In *this* context it means $\underbrace{f\circ f\circ ...... \circ f}_{n\text{ times}}$ or in other words:

$f^n(x) = \underbrace{f(f(f(....(}_{n\text{ times}}x)....)))$

or in other words.

You take $f(x)= y_1$.  Then $f(f(x))= f(y_1)= y_2$ and $f(f(f(x)))= f(y_2)=y_3$ and you keep repeating $n$ times.

So if $f(x) = ax + b$ then

$f^2(x) = f(f(x)) = f(ax+b) = a(ax + b) + b = a^2x + 2b$

and

$f^3(x) = f(f(f(x))) = f(a^2x + 2b)= a(a^2x + 2b) + b = a^3x + 3b$.

And so on.

=======

But bear in mind that although this is the most *common* usage, and IMO, the most legitimate usage, you will find cases where people mean something else.  It's unfortunate.

Occasionally, but *not* here, you will see some texts mean $f^n(x) = (f(x))^n = \underbrace{f(x)\times f(x)\times.....\times f(x)}$.

It's important that you realize some people use one and some use the other they mean *completely* different things.

As most people use the notation:

$f(f(f(...(x))) = f^n(x) \ne (f(x))^n = f(x)\times f(x)\times ... \times f(x)$.

Completely different things.

Comment: In this context, it's the first one, since $f^n(x) =f(f^{n-1}(x))$

Comment: @David; the three things I listed are all the same things.

Answer (score 0):

$f^1(x) =f(x)$ needs no explanation

According to the expression $f^n(x) =f(f^{n-1}(x))$, we have $f^2(x)=f(f(x))$

Similarly, $f^3(x) =f(f^{2}(x)) = f(f(f(x)))$

You can now see the idea. You are applying $f$ $n$ times (take $x$, apply $f$, take the result of that, apply $f$ again, and so on...)